# Using \collectcell in {tabu}

Tags: tabu, collcell

I have a document with tables where I automatically create cross-references based on the contents of some cells. For this, I use the `collcell` package to pass the cell contents to a macro.

I'm currently using `tabular` (with `array`) and `tabularx`, but I'd like to move some of these tables to `tabu`. Unfortunately, `tabu` and `\collectcell` don't play well together. MNWE (I replaced the linkification automation by a simple use of `\meaning` to show what's going on):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\showmeaning#1->#2.{#2}
\newcommand{\linkify}[1]{\def\linkifycontent{#1}\expandafter\showmeaning\meaning\linkifycontent.}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\ttfamily}l}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell{\linkify}}t<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\ttfamily\collectcell{\linkify}}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{6em}{TU}
  foo & bar \\
\end{tabularx}
\qquad
\begin{tabu}{TU}
  foo & bar \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: tabu-collcell.pdf]

With `tabular` or `tabularx`, `\collectcell` captures the content of the cell. But with `tabu`, it also captures tokens inserted before the cell content, including `\tabu@cellleft` which is automatically inserted by `tabu`.

What can I replace `\collectcell` with in my column definitions so that only the cell content is captured?

I want to keep column definitions that work both in tabu and non-tabu environments, because I use both. I can't just make the decision based on the environment names, because I define some wrappers around `tabularx` and I use other environments from the `tabu` package (`longtabu` is one of my reasons for moving to `tabu`).

Ideally I'd like to keep being able to nest column type definitions (as I do now with `T` using `t`, and `\ttfamily` not ending up in the collected cell content), but if it's really needed I can arrange to always put `collectcell` at the innermost level around the built-in column types (`l`, `X`, `p`, …).

Comment: `tabu` doesn't play well with many other packages, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out not to require much code. Override `\collectcell` to read everything up to `\tabu@cellleft`, then call the original `\collectcell`. Use `\tabu@ifenvir` to check whether the current environment is a `tabu` or `longtabu`.

```
\let\collectcell@notabu\collectcell
\def\collectcell@intabu#1#2\tabu@cellleft{#2\tabu@cellleft\collectcell@notabu{#1}}
\def\collectcell{\tabu@ifenvir\collectcell@intabu\collectcell@notabu}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You can use `cmd` option for cells, rows or columns with `tblr` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\showmeaning#1->#2.{#2}
\newcommand{\linkify}[1]{\def\linkifycontent{#1}\expandafter\showmeaning\meaning\linkifycontent.}

\NewColumnType{T}{X[font=\sffamily,t,cmd=\linkify]}
\NewColumnType{U}{X[font=\ttfamily,l,cmd=\linkify]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{TU}
 \hline
  foo & bar \\
 \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]